# Override Constants in Protractor Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have these two boolean variables in a configuration object which I pass to a constant of the angular application.

These booleans are both checked at the point the page resolves. If both are true it stays in the page and if one or the other are true it bounces the user to a specified page.

See the code below

```
angular
.module('ecardGeneratorPrototype')
.constant('config', 
{
    "enable-file-upload": true,
    "enable-webcam": true
```

I then check these in a resolve function:

```
.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'home',
    resolve : {
        choice: ['$route', '$window', 'config', function ($route, $window, config) {
            if ( config["enable-file-upload"] && config["enable-webcam"] ){
              //return
              return;
            }
            else
            {
              if ( config["enable-file-upload"] ){
                //go to the file upload page
                //$log( "display the file upload page" );
                $window.location.href = '#/file-upload';
              }
              else if ( config["enable-webcam"] ){
                //$log( "display the webcam page" );
                $window.location.href = '#/webcam';
              }
            }
            return;
        }]
    }
  })
```

My question is can I override these constants so I can test the pages are being redirected correctly in my protractor tests?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can mock your module and provide the constant you want in a beforeEach function.

Something like that:

```js
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("ecardGeneratorPrototype", function ($provide) {
    $provide.constant("enable-file-upload", false);
}));
```